# cannot display html table with TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Just want to display html table with TCPDF but getting errors instead.

**Here is my code:**

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">                

<tr>
    <td >        
    aaaaa    
    </td>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >   
    bbbb
   </td>  
   </tr>     
   <td rowspan="2">    
   hhhhh  
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>    
    iiii        
    </td>
    <td>
    jjjj        
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
EOD;
```

But when I replace my html table code with following html table code (from TCPDF examples), it displays correctly:

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">COL 1 - ROW 1<br />COLSPAN 3</td>
        <td>COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">COL 2 - ROW 2 - COLSPAN 2<br />text line<br />text line</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>COL 3 - ROW 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
EOD;
```

Could you please check my html table code and help me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `<tr>`, you have an extra `</tr>`, making the document invalid. Indented, your HTML is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaa</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">bbbb</td>
    </tr>
        <td rowspan="2">hhhhh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>iiii</td>
        <td>jjjj</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```